# Increase X-RateLimit-Limit in laravel using throttle middleware

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

I can find ways to decrease the value but in my case I am running many asynchronous API calls and need to increase the X-RateLimit-Limit to something more than 100 to work.

### Kindly suggest alternatives.

following is the response which I am getting

P.S - I am using auth middleware also

---

```
eHTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
```

Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 11:18:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.35
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.35
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
Retry-After: 24
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImtuSU5EMXo0YXlrSU1MWnVnUFRyeUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicVVkMU55V2lkcHNvMkRqaFlCUFZnK3lcL0pRckNpcjMyZll3UkVaWXNEYWhSazdcL2Jub3M4QmtpZDhDQWVCZjhzWE5KV0paaGlZMGJOQ1J1TGNFYnhkdz09IiwibWFjIjoiZTNlNzY3MDc2ZWExMjBhZDI0MjA3NzNjYjE5YWU1NmIzZmEyY2RiOWI4NDBmOGI5MjVmN2E2ZTUzNDE3YjdmNyJ9; expires=Fri, 10-Mar-2017 13:18:25 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkRoSWV2dzFHV3F5YUJNR2tCMEhKSUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTzdhOW12ZFozNnJtaW5vRFBHdFVZV1l2SDdXcEpvdEN6MGdRTkZsRzFoeU9yb2VXTDN5cVA0a1d5NnZ1MCtEMTRKNFRES1ZsODg5YmswY2F5cEN0c1E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImY5YjYyMmNiNDE1YzgxYmQ3NzE5NjYyMTk0YmEzNzU2NTg4MzZhZWYyNDVjMWVkMzJmNzRiMmUwODFjYjRiYWMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 10-Mar-2017 13:18:25 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Content-Length: 18
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Too Many Attempts.

Comment: the `throttle` middleware accepts parameters to increase or decreate the rate limit.

Comment: Setting the throttle middleware greater than 60 is ignored.  It is only working to throttle less than 60.  Even when I change the default `$maxAttempts = 60`, it has no effect except for less than 60.

Answer (score 5):

You can set throttling parameters as in the image:

[image]

Comment: yes , ,tried but when I am increasing it over 60, nothing happen the limit stays at 60

Comment: Try to dump your parameter directly in the Throttle class (http://prntscr.com/eir6u6). Is it set correctly?

Comment: Try to clear your cookies. Or dig into the Throttle class and try to find a problem there.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt to do set the API thottle greater than 60 like the following will be usurped by the setting in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
// routes/api.php
Route::get('myapi/{value}/{anothervalue}', 'MyApiController@getStuff')->middleware('throttle:100,1');
```

For the above to work, increase the limit in `app/Http/Kernel.php` according to your specific requirements:

```
    'api' => [
        'throttle:500,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```